# Performance difference between virtual dom and dirty-checking

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, angularjs-digest, virtual-dom

I am newbie to react. Realy want to know performance difference between virtual dom of react and dirty checking of angular.

1. React uses `“diffing”` algorithm.

   a. how it works?
   b. Does it keeps `two copies of trees`? Comparing two trees doesn't it costly?
2. React doesn't directly manipulate `heavyweight` parts.

   a. What it refers to?

Angular(Angular 1)

1. Angular keeps watch on data which are actually present in DOM not on
   all scope variables.

   a. Doesn't it better than comparing two trees?
2. Angular runs `digest cycle` and after it becomes stable it manipulate
   dom.

   a. What is the advantage of react virtual dom here?

Answer (score -2):

Don't fall for these marketing gimmicks.
In the end, it all comes down to the browser or platform on which these framework runs.
React JSX and Virtual DOM can be separated as it is a tech which can be utilized. However, once React becomes big it's a big mess of spaghetti and hated for functional UI people to work, maybe the developers can.
However, with AngularJS or Angular having separation f concerns as part of design philosophy templates can be separated, thus speeding the time to develop and push to the market. Also, the community support is good.

What you really need to evolve is the platform while retaining open web spes(?) such as component. React is killing it.

I would recommend go with Angular either version, if you are planning to use or make full blown apps.